# Why my React Native Android App build failing?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting the below error, please check the image.

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the react-native error since Nov 4th, 2022.

Learn more at
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

I think you should update the react-native version

or

add the below code in 'android/buld.gradle' file inside allprojects

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support Sergey, You solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you'll have to provide a little more info. Because for the time being Is your AVM running? Because for the time being your Virtual device seems to fail with app you're making.